# Passing a multivariable anonymous function in a Dplyr R pipe

Tags: r, anonymous-function

Consider the following example dataframe

```
df  <- data.frame(x=c("A", "A", "B", "B"), y=c(1,2,1,2))
```

I am trying to understand how to use anonymous function with pipes

I would like to create another column type using an anonymous function

```
  x y  type
1 A 1 type1
2 A 2 type2
3 B 1 type2
4 B 2 type2
```

Of course I can use if_else():

```
df= df  %>%  mutate(type = if_else(.$x =='A' & .$y==1  , "type1",  "type2"))
```

but suppose  the if_else function doesn't exist and you want to use an anonymous function:

I know I can create the new column like this:

```
df$type =mapply(df$x,df$y, FUN=function(x,y) if ((x=='A')  && (y==1))  "type1"   else "type2")
```

but I also want to use a pipe

```
df$type =df %>% mutate(type=mapply(.$x,.$y, FUN=function(x,y) if ((x=='A')  && (y==1))  "type1"   else "type2"))
```

yields the following:

```
  x y type.x type.y type.type
1 A 1      A      1     type1
2 A 2      A      2     type2
3 B 1      B      1     type2
4 B 2      B      2     type2
```

which gives two additional unwanted colunms. if I remove .$x and .$y I get an error

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>% mutate(type=mapply(.$x,.$y, FUN=function(x,y) if ((x=='A')  && (y==1))  "type1"   else "type2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `purrr` equivalent, using `map2()`:

```
df %>% mutate(type= purrr::map2(.$x,.$y, 
                                .f = function(x,y) if (x == 'A'  && y == 1) {"type1"
                                  } else {"type2"}
                                ))
```

Although you don't really have to use an anonymous function for this example. 
I would use the `case_when()` function in dplyr:

```
df %>% mutate(type = case_when(x == "A" & y == 1 ~ "type1",
                               TRUE ~ "type2"))
```